# How to run gurobi on colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, gurobi

I have the gurobi solver installed on my computer. Is there a way I can connect and use it on Google Colab? Can this be done without connecting to the local runtime?

Comment: _Is there a way I can connect and use it on Google Colab ?_ That depends on what exactly you mean by _connect and use it on Google Colab_. _Can this be done without connecting to local runtime ?_ What local runtime?

Comment: I meant call (import) the solver in Colab.

Comment: Can you be more specific? You want to import the module to use it in the notebook in Colab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the gurobi version 9.1.1 you can now just do a classic pip installation like this

```
%pip install -i https://pypi.gurobi.com gurobipy
```

But you have same limitations (this is a limited free version):

With Gurobi 9.1.1, a pip installation of the product will automatically include a size-limited (2000 variables, 2000 linear constraints, and 200 quadratic constraints) license that should work in a Docker container, which is used by Google Colab.

Sources:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/Gurobi/modeling-examples/blob/master/intro_to_modeling/introduction_to_modeling_gcl.ipynb

https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360073699632-Google-colab-and-Gurobi

Answer (score 0):

This is not easily possible due to license restrictions. Imagine you set up a Colab notebook using a cloud license: everyone who can clone the notebook is able to use your license and your cloud credits.

Similar problems apply for academic licenses: A university would have to expose its license server or make VPN access available to the world.

If you manage your own Colab or Jupyter server, there is no issue with Gurobi because you have control over the machine and the environment.